# Div is floating way to high

Tags: css

For some reason the Menu div is floating too high when the menu is up but when it closes it's perfect. I'm not really sure what to do to bring that Menu div down to touch the right side div under it

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
} 

#footer-content {
    display: none;
} 

#footer-left {
    width: 20%;
    height: 145px;  
    float: left;
    background-color: #52291c;/*#805f4c;*/
    opacity: 0.8;
} #footer-left h3 {
    width: 95%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin-top: 95px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: right;
} #footer-left h3 a {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    text-transform: lowercase;  
} 

#footer-right {
    width: 80%;
    height: 145px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #B29F63; /*#B29F63*/
    opacity: 0.3;   
} #footer-right ul {
    margin: 30px 15px;
    font-size: 24px;    
} #footer-right ul li a {
    color: #52291c;
}

.doing-tricks {
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    left: 21%;
    top: 132px; 
    font-size: 24px;
    z-index: 100;
} .doing-tricks a {
    color: #52291c; 
}

.toggle-footer {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #52291c;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
    background: #B29F63;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(178,159,99,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(178,159,99,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(178,159,99,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(178,159,99,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(178,159,99,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(254,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(178,159,99,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-top-left-radius:  5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rFdwr/1/

Comment: aaaaaaaaa I did an example and was right away to show you an example and you removed your Q...

Answer (score 6):

Make the `.doing-tricks`'s position `absolute`instead of `relative`

```
.doing-tricks {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    ...
}
```

Then you'll need to adjust the top positions of your texts inside the footer.